# extract month function not working in postgres

Tags: php, sql, laravel, postgresql

I have the table test and want to extract the month from the field month which is character varying.

distinct month Field value as `'August-2020','September-2020'`

I have tried as `SELECT extract(Month from to_date(t.month, '%Month-%YYYY')) as test FROM test as t`
but getting the error
**invalid value "ugust-2020" for "MONTH"
DETAIL:  The given value did not match any of the allowed values for this field.**

I have two server in one server working fine as extracting (8,8,9,9) but in another server getting error.

Answer (score 1):

Your format mask is wrong and you should be using:

```
Month-YYYY
```

Sample query:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(month FROM TO_DATE(t.month, 'Month-YYYY')) AS month
FROM test t;
```

Comment: Do you know why the same works in postgres12 and not earlier version ?

Comment: Yes I tried and it is working https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=568dffdd5c89a3636c7d638ed3eedb19.

Comment: need for postgres11

Comment: The above should work on any version of Postgres supporting `TO_DATE`.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30  I would assume it is due to this "Adjust to_timestamp()/to_date() functions to be more forgiving of template mismatches" https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/release-12.html